# .NET equivalent to node http-proxy

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, angular, proxy

I am looking for a .NET solution to proxy API requests between a client application and a rest API. One solution that requires node.js back end I found is node http-proxy following this http://shawnsimondeveloper.com/nodeproxyangular/ example.

The .NET proxy needs to be able to attach a certificate to the api requests for authentication. The proxy should take any request and pass it through to the destination URL.

What options are available for .NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to stick with the node solution, here is the simple code used to proxy a request with a certificate to the API. The key was to add the key, cert, and ca properties to the target in the proxy options.

```
'use strict';
let fs = require('fs');
let https = require('https');
let express = require('express');
let httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
let privateKey = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/certs/server.key', 'utf8');
let certificate = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/certs/cert.pem', 'utf8');
let caChain = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/certs/cachain.pem', 'utf8');
let staticRoot = __dirname + '/';

let httpsOptions = {
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate,
    ca: [caChain]
};

let proxyOptions = {
    target: {
        host: 'api.host.com',
        protocol: 'https:',
        key: privateKey,
        cert: certificate,
        ca: caChain,
    },
    changeOrigin: true
};

let app = express();
let apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer(proxyOptions);
app.use(express.static(staticRoot));
app.all('/api/*', function(req, res) {
    console.log(Date().toString('yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss') + ' - API Request Proxied');
    apiProxy.web(req, res, proxyOptions);
});

https.createServer(httpsOptions, app).listen(3001, function(){
    console.log('https server listening on port 3001');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go with nginx, though their documentation can be frustrating at times.

http://nginx.org/

Comment: Can you provide any reasoning behind your recommendation?

Comment: @SkiGeek It's free & works on windows. No reason to try to create a proxy when they already exist.

Comment: I will have to look to see how it fits in with our infrastructure. Currently I do not understand how this is any more beneficial than the Node.js solution linked in my question.

Comment: @SkiGeek Using a program that's heavily used is usually preferable to one that is home-rolled because you're probably not going to be the person to maintain it.  Because of that, it's best to use something like IIS, Apache, Nginx, etc than to just custom write it unless there's something forcing your hand.

Comment: @SkiGeek you might also be able to use IIS but I'm not qualified enough to say whether it can do exactly what you're asking.